# Is this a selection sort or a bubble sort?

Tags: java

Is this a selection sort? I think it is Bubble Sort because I'm using (dot)compareTo. I look at different sources on the internet so I can make one. Here is the codes.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SelectionSort {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] row = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "grapes", "mango", "avocado"};
        int min  = row.length;
        for(int m = 0; m < min-1; m++) {
            for (int n = m+1; n < row.length; n++) {
                if(row[m].compareTo(row[n]) > 0){
                    String bar = row[m];
                    row[m] = row[n];
                    row[n] = bar;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Expected Outcome: " + Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

Comment: Every sort method will use a comparison at a  moment, `compareTo` doesn't give any clue

Answer (score 1):

this is not selection sort
I selection sort in each iteration you find minimum value and put it to the proper location. See this picture 
[image]

A simple implementation show here:
https://www.javatpoint.com/selection-sort-in-java

```
public class SelectionSortExample {  
    public static void selectionSort(int[] arr){  
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)  
        {  
            int index = i;  
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){  
                if (arr[j] < arr[index]){  
                    index = j;//searching for lowest index  
                }  
            }  
            int smallerNumber = arr[index];   
            arr[index] = arr[i];  
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;  
        }  
    }  
       
    public static void main(String a[]){  
        int[] arr1 = {9,14,3,2,43,11,58,22};  
        System.out.println("Before Selection Sort");  
        for(int i:arr1){  
            System.out.print(i+" ");  
        }  
        System.out.println();  
          
        selectionSort(arr1);//sorting array using selection sort  
         
        System.out.println("After Selection Sort");  
        for(int i:arr1){  
            System.out.print(i+" ");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not Selection Sort (Milad already answered this), but it is also **not Bubble Sort.**

The way you can tell that it is not bubble sort, is because bubble sort compares pairs of **items that are next to each-other** (ex: compares items at index 0-1, 1-2, 2-3... and swaps if necessary). In your code, when m=0, the inner loop will compare **item at index 0 with all the other items in the array.**

**Bubble Sort in Java:**

```
public void sort( int[] array) {

    boolean isSorted;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        isSorted = true;
        for (var j = 1;  j < array.length - i ; j++) 
            if (array[j] < array[j - 1]) {           
                swap(array, j, j - 1);
                isSorted = false;
            }
        if (isSorted)  
            return;
    }
}


private void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
    var temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
}
```